# Wordpress: Create theme-unspecific shortcodes?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, shortcode

I know how to create my own shortcodes within the functions.php of a specific wordpress-theme. Is there a way to create global shortcodes, that work independently of the theme in use?

Comment: the shortcode function isn't limited to functions.php. You can also plop in a plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create my-custom-global-shortcode.php inside wp-content/plugins/my-custom-global-shortcode/
2. Paste this code inside that file and you have yourself a functioning global shortcode.
3. Modify the shortcode_handler function to do your bidding

   ```
    /*
    Plugin Name: Shortcode Plugin
    Plugin URI: 
    Description: My Global Shortcode
    Version: 1.0
    Author: 
    Author URI: 
    */

    //register [my-custom-global-shortcode]
    add_shortcode("my-custom-global-shortcode", "shortcode_handler");

    // the function called with the shortcode
    function shortcode_handler() {
      $html = '<div>Hello World!</div>';
      return $html;
    }
    ?>
   ```